# how can I render an url on google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have this in a cell:

1. import requests
2. import json
3. response = requests.get("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod? 
   api_key=YF6oJUH1StX0gV4o51ATSsn3qr9S7zzCLjZypQYu")
4. json_data=response.json()
5. address=json_data["hdurl"]
6. print(address)

and the outcome is: https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2004/LightPollutionPan_Slovinsky_2048.jpg

The problem is how to "open" the url?
I have tried %%HTML and gave me a gray screen, I tried also webbrowser but I got False as the outcome, this seems to be easy but I can't figure out, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't expose your api_key publically.

Comment: Yeah, you might want to reset the API key to prevent its abuse.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the remote image using IPython module.

```
import IPython
IPython.display.Image(url='https://google.com/favicon.ico')
```

[image: image render]

So the code that you wantis something like this:

```
import requests
import json
from IPython.display import Image as RenderImage

response = requests.get("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=YF6oJUH1StX0gV4o51ATSsn3qr9S7zzCLjZypQYu")
json_data=response.json()
address=json_data["hdurl"]

RenderImage(url='https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2004/LightPollutionPan_Slovinsky_960_labeled.jpg')
```

[image: colab]

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark this as the answer, if this helped you. :)